# leafletjs: polyline list into geojson

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geojson

i have list of polylines. i want to make it more organized. how can i make my polyline list into the GeoJSON?

```
var point1 = new coordsToLatLngArray(0, 100);
var point2 = new coordsToLatLngArray(200, 150);
var point3 = new coordsToLatLngArray(400, 70);
var point4 = new coordsToLatLngArray(10, 70);
var point5 = new coordsToLatLngArray(90, 50);
var pointList = [point1, point2, point3, point4, point5];

var firstpolyline = new L.polyline(pointList, {
color: 'red',
weight: 3,
opacity: 0.5,
smoothFactor: 1

});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

i have trying to work with: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html
but it didn't work. my line were outside the map:

```
var geojsonFeature = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates":
    [
        [0,0], 
        [-100,100]
    ]
}];
var myStyle = {
    "color": "#ff7800",
    "weight": 5,
    "opacity": 0.65
};
var myLayer = L.geoJson(coordsToLatLngArray(), {style: myStyle }).addTo(l);
myLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);
```

Demo of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4k1psuh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will only be passed a single argument to `coordsToLatLngArray`, an array:

```
[longitude,latitude]
```

The function must look like this:

```
var coordsToLatLngArray = function(c) {
    var e = fixLat(c[1]),
        t = c[0],
        n = e / latScale + latScaleVal / 2 / latScale,
        r = t / longScale + longScaleVal / 2 / longScale;
    return [-n, r]
};
```

Note: in geoJSON a coordinate has a reversed order, `[longitude,latitude]`, so the coordinates must be:

```
        [
            [100, 0],
            [150, 200],
            [70,400],
            [70,10],
            [50,90]
        ]
```

to draw the feature call:

```
    var myLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
        style: myStyle,
        coordsToLatLng:coordsToLatLngArray
    }).addTo(l);
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/Ltaw5teo/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltaw5teo/)